# Rewrite url in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hello I would like to know if it is possible to rewrite this:

- www.example.com/view/page.html

(Where view is a directory)

to:

- www.example.com/page.html

by using a rule inside htaccess file located in the directory called "view".

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `.htaccess` file on your root folder and write the code below on it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page.html$ /view/page.html [NC,L]
```

You should be able to access to www.example.com/page.html and see the page.html page without restarting Apache.

Comment: Thank you!! I have a doubt, I am making a kind of social network and for example in facebook when you log in it just shows you its domain name in the initial page, the same happens in the page where you register. So, my idea is to make something like that, is it possible with htaccess? I Just want to show the name of the domain when I am in the page right after I logged in or in the page where I have to register.